# How to Import Nuke (.chan) format in blender?

Tags: add-on, camera, tracking

I am trying to import the Nuke camera track in the Blender with **.chan format**. But it's not perfectly imported.
It shows a very small on-grid and perfectly tracks, but the same camera fully tracks in max. can any buddy help me out? how to exactly use .chan format

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4):

There's a built-in add-on for importing Nuke .chan files:  [Nuke](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/anim_nuke_chan.html). Be sure to read the tips and limitations in the manual.

To enable it

- Edit -> Preferences
- Select the *Add-ons* tab
- type *nuke*
- click the checkbox to enable:

To import a .chan file

- File->Import
- Select `Nuke (.chan)`
- use the file browser to navigate to and select the .chan file you want to import.
- Be sure to set the camera sensor size to match the size you used in Nuke to do the export.

[image: File menu showing Nuke in the Import submenu]

[image: Edit preferences showing add-on tab with a search for nuke]

Comment: I already activate this and import it with the addon, but the scale of  seen is very small,

Comment: Did you set the sensor size during the import?